# Is there a Criteria equivalent to using HQL array subscript?

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria

I need to retrieve entities that have specific values at specific positions in an associated list.

I can achieve this using HQL as follows:

```
from Cat c
where c.kittens[0].name = 'whiskers'
and c.kittens[1].name = 'mittens'
```

I now want to add this restriction to an existing search which uses the criteria API. I don't see anything similar to the array subscript notation in that API. What is the equivalent using criteria?